# SMS Broadcast Receiver just works after resetting permission on android 8 and 6

Tags: android, permissions

I've written an app that needs to listen for new SMS. I've used run time permissions for android M and later. 
The code works well on android 7.x. But when I want to run it on android 6.x or 8.x, it won't get new SMS until I deny and then grant the SMS permission from settings. 
After running app on android 6.x and 8.x, it wants SMS permission and I allow it, but as I said, it wont get new SMS until I open settings, deny permission and then grant that. 
Does anyone know what's the problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
In android 6 and 8, granting READ_SMS permission is not enough. So, you have to use RECEIVE_SMS to get new SMS.